# Google Spreadsheet script showing some odd behavior

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I hope someone could help me with this little problem that i am having.

I am using the script below to decode vin number directly on a google spreadsheet, and it is working almost 100%.

```
function VinNumberonEdit(){

var sheetName = "Sheet1";

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();

var activeRange = ss.getActiveRange();

if (activeRange.isBlank() && ss.getSheetName() == sheetName){

activeRange.offset(0, 1).clearContent()

activeRange.offset(0, 2).clearContent()

activeRange.offset(0, 3).clearContent()

}

else if(activeRange.getColumn() == 1 && activeRange.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == sheetName){

var vin = ss.getActiveCell().getValue()

vin = encodeURI(vin)

var url = "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVinValues/"+vin+"?format=json"

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

var w = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

activeRange.offset(0, 1).setValue(w.Results[0].Make)

activeRange.offset(0, 2).setValue(w.Results[0].Model)

activeRange.offset(0, 3).setValue(w.Results[0].ModelYear)

}

}
```

The problem I am having is when I add some more lines or when I format those cells. For some reason it adds three more unwanted columns.

Probably my problem is in that first if statement:

```
if (activeRange.isBlank() && ss.getSheetName() == sheetName){

activeRange.offset(0, 1).clearContent()

activeRange.offset(0, 2).clearContent()

activeRange.offset(0, 3).clearContent()

}
```

I uploaded a gif to show you guys what is my struggle.

https://giphy.com/embed/hqO5pFZZ2xWyQva66e

Does Anyone have an idea of how to fix it? I am not a programmer. I built this Frankenstein to help me on my job but now I am stuck in this little issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function VinNumberonEdit(e){
  //e.source.toast('Flag1');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  //e.source.toast('Flag2');
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet188')return;
  if(e.range.isBlank() && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.columnEnd==1){
    //e.source.toast('Flag3');
    e.range.offset(0, 1).clearContent();
    e.range.offset(0, 2).clearContent();
    e.range.offset(0, 3).clearContent();
  }else if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.columnEnd==1 && e.range.rowStart>1){
    //e.source.toast('Flag4');
    var vin=encodeURI(e.range.getValue());
    var url="https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVinValues/"+vin+"?format=json";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var w=JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    //e.source.toast('flag5');
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(w.Results[0].Make);
    e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue(w.Results[0].Model);
    e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue(w.Results[0].ModelYear);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong (if anything) with your code but this works for me.  It was wierd though I couldn't get `e.value` to work but `e.range.getValue()` does work.  Don't forget to change the sheet number.

Comment: That's is weird, the same behavior is happening, do you think that's somehow related to the trigger (onEdit) that I created to run the function VinNumberonEdit?

I had to use it cause the function onEdit has some issues when calling an api.

Comment: No. You needed an installable trigger because the script required permissions but I don't see why that has anything to do with e.value not working.  I was thinking that it might have something to do with the fact that I was pasting the vin numbers in rather that typing them.  Other than that is it working for you now?

Comment: I finally watched the video and I think I stopped from creating any extra columns.  The problem was that it was trying to clear content on three columns that were not there and I guess that's why it created the three columns.  But now the script requires that the range can only be 1 column wide and it has to be in column1

Comment: If you want to see the extra parameters in the event object.  Do a `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));`

Comment: That work like a charm my friend! That is awesome. Now I am going to take this piece of code and study it to truly understand it. As I told you I am not a programmer. THANK YOU once more!

Comment: That's great...Glad to help.  Here's a reference to the [SpreadsheetApp Class in the Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app).